# Maven in Netbeans8: how to add jars to local repository

Tags: maven, netbeans, jar

I use Maven bundled in NetBeans8. I have a lot of Maven projects, but also a lot of jar files provided by third parties which are not available from any online Maven repository.

I have to use these jars in one of my Maven projects. I read in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955695/1983997) that I should copy the jars in my local repository! How can I do that in NetBeans with my bundled Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do it from the command line as explained in your link. Maven is in `netbeans installation folder/java/maven/bin/mvn.bat` on Windows. Not sure on other platform.

Alternatively, you can expand your project's "Dependencies" folder, right click on the jar and select "Manually install artifact".